# How to open and work with a very large .SQL file that was generated in a dump?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very large .SQL file, of 90 GB

It was generated with a dump on a server:

```
mysqldump -u root -p siafi > /home/user_1/siafi.sql
```

I downloaded this .SQL file on a computer with Ubuntu 16.04 and MySQL Community Server (8.0.16). It has 8GB of RAM

So I did these steps in Terminal:

```
# Access
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p

# I create a database with the same name to receive the .SQL information
CREATE DATABASE siafi;

# I establish the privileges. User reinaldo
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON siafi.* to reinaldo@localhost;

# Enable the changes
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

# Then I open another terminal and type command for the created database to receive the data from the .SQL file
mysql --user=reinaldo --password="type_here" --database=siafi < /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/test/siafi.sql
```

I typed these same commands with other .SQL files, only minor ones, with a maximum of 2GB. And it worked normally

But this 90GB file is processing for over twelve hours without stopping. I do not know if it's working

Please, is there any more efficient way to do this? Maybe splitting the .SQL file?

Comment: https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html think this will be useful -time grafh

Comment: I think this can help too : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/219954/very-large-mysql-backup

Comment: Let's back up a step...  Is the question really about loading a .sql or about cloning the database?  There are ways to clone that do not involve the slow step you are asking about, and may be faster.

Comment: Can you avoid doing this with mysqldump? It's much better to take a different type of snapshot.

Comment: If you're talking about actually opening the file in an editor so you can then split it manually, you might want something like [EmEdit](https://www.emeditor.com/).

Comment: It is a server that has already been terminated, so I hurried the dump @Evert

Comment: It is a server that has already been terminated, so I hurried the dump. I now need to use this .SQL file to recreate the database on another computer @RickJames

Comment: By "terminated", I assume that you do not have access to the server; hence, all you have is the dump?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';

Comment: Yes, now I only have the dump @RickJames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things that might be helpful:

1. Use `pv` to see how much of the .sql file has already been read. This can give you a progress bar which at least tells you it's not suck.
2. Log into MySQL and use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what MySQL currently is executing. If it's still running, just let it run to completion.

If turned on, it might really help to turn off the binlog for the duration of the restore. Another thing that may or may not be helpful... if you have the choice, try to use the fastest disks available. You may have this kind of option if you're running on hosters like Amazon. You're going to really feel the pain if you're (for example) doing this on a standard EC2 host.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I need to install the pipe viewer first? And then type something like: pv siafi.sql | mysql --user=reinaldo --password="type_here" --database=siafi < /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/test/siafi.sql

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves: the general syntax would be `pv file.sql | mysql`. pv already outputs everything to STDOUT so you don't need to also use `<`.

Comment: I typed: pv /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/test/siafi.sql | mysql --user = reinaldo --password = "type_here" --database = siafi </home/reinaldo/Documents/Code/test/siafi.sql

Comment: However, after more than an hour the percentage did not leave the 0%

Comment: However, I typed SHOW PROCESSLIST; in another Terminal and the task is being done

Answer (score 2):

Break the file up into smaller chunks and process them separately.

You're probably hitting the logging high-water mark and mysql is trying to roll everything back, and that is a slow process.

Split the file into approx 1Gb chunks, breaking on whole lines. Perhaps using:

```
split -l 1000000 bigfile.sql part.
```

Then run them in order using your current command.

You'll have to experiment with `split` to get the size right, and you haven't said what your OS is, and `split` implementations/options vary. `split --number=100` make work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bohemian I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, 8G of RAM. I typed this command in Terminal: split -l 1000000 /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/test/siafi.sql part.

Comment: After about 40 minutes the processing stopped. Were new files to be created? No created after

Comment: And then I typed: pv /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/test/siafi.sql | mysql --user = reinaldo --password = "type_here" --database = siafi </home/reinaldo/Documents/Code/test/siafi.sql

Comment: However, after more than an hour the percentage did not leave the 0%

Comment: However, I typed SHOW PROCESSLIST; in another Terminal and the task is being done. I guess that's all there is to wait, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party tools like
https://philiplb.de/sqldumpsplitter3/

Very easy to use, can define size, location etc...

Or use this one also
same but interface its bit colorful and use to use

https://sqldumpsplitter.net/

Comment: Please don't write in ALL CAPS. It's considered bad style.